# Error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric, using Hashbytes function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, ssis, case

I have a legacy SSIS package that needs updating.  Specifically it used to only add new records and must now update and end date or delete records as appropriate.  elsewhere in the package I've been using the Hashbytes function with great success to evaluate which rows need to be updated by taking matching datasets from both databases and then comparing them as part of a conditional split.  The problem I'm having revolves around a case statement in the source query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
DTBL_STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID,
FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_STUDENT_GRADE,
DTBL_TESTS.TEST_NAME,
DTBL_SCHOOL_DATES.DATE_VALUE AS Assessment_Date,
DTBL_SCHOOL_DATES.SIS_SCHOOL_YEAR AS Assessment_Year,
left( CASE
    WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_TEXT = 'NA'
    THEN CASE
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT_CODE = 'INTE' THEN 'High'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT_CODE = 'STRA' THEN 'Some'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT_CODE = 'BNCH' THEN 'Low'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT IN ('High', 'Some', 'Low') THEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT
             ELSE FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_TEXT
         END
    ELSE CASE
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_TEXT LIKE '%.0000'
             THEN REPLACE(FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_TEXT, '.0000', '')
             ELSE FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_TEXT
         END
END,12) AS TEST_SCORE_TEXT,
CASE
    WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_TEXT = 'NA'
    THEN CASE
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT_CODE = 'INTE' THEN '1'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT_CODE = 'STRA' THEN '3'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT_CODE = 'BNCH' THEN '4'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT = 'High' THEN '1'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT = 'Some' THEN '3'
             WHEN FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT = 'Low'  THEN '4'
             ELSE '0'
         END
    ELSE FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_VALUE
END AS TEST_SCORE_VALUE,
FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_PERCENTILE_SCORE,
DTBL_SCHOOLS.SCHOOL_HR_ID
FROM K12INTEL_DW.DTBL_TESTS
JOIN K12INTEL_DW.FTBL_TEST_SCORES  ON FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TESTS_KEY         =     
DTBL_TESTS.TESTS_KEY
JOIN K12INTEL_DW.DTBL_SCHOOL_DATES ON DTBL_SCHOOL_DATES.SCHOOL_DATES_KEY =   
FTBL_TEST_SCORES.SCHOOL_DATES_KEY
JOIN K12INTEL_DW.DTBL_STUDENTS     ON DTBL_STUDENTS.STUDENT_KEY          =   
FTBL_TEST_SCORES.STUDENT_KEY
JOIN K12INTEL_DW.DTBL_SCHOOLS      ON DTBL_SCHOOLS.SCHOOL_KEY            = 
FTBL_TEST_SCORES.SCHOOL_KEY
WHERE DTBL_SCHOOL_DATES.SIS_SCHOOL_YEAR = 2014 
AND DTBL_STUDENTS.STUDENT_CURRENT_DISTRICT_CODE = '2180'
AND FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_STUDENT_GRADE IN ('PS', 'PK', 'KG', '01', '02',  
'03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08')
AND DTBL_TESTS.TEST_VENDOR IS NOT NULL
AND FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_HIGHEST_SCORE_INDICATOR IN ('Yes', '--')
```

The 3 values I need to hash for comparison are:
TEST_SCORE_TEXT
TEST_SCORE_VALUE
Assessment_Date

It looks like it's choking on TEST_SCORE_VALUE in the function:

```
   HASHBYTES('SHA1',ISNULL(#Dware.TEST_SCORE_TEXT,'')+convert(varchar(10),ISNULL(TEST_SCORE_VALUE,''))+convert(varchar(50),(ISNULL(Assessment_Date,'')))) as SourceHash
```

This is where I get the error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric".  I've tried putting my source query into a subquery and doing a select*, (function) from that source query.  I've tried putting the case statement into the hashbytes function, and I've tried using a temp table.  My assumption is that it's getting the underlying value rather than the value generated by the case statement but I don't know why,or how to fix it so that I get the numeric values I'm expecting/wanting.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_VALUE` is numeric, then look at your `CASE` statement that creates `TEST_SCORE_VALUE`. You create a string by evaluating `TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT_CODE` and `TEST_PRIMARY_RESULT`, etc, but your final `ELSE` statement is probably returning a numeric value (`FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_VALUE`).

I believe Sql Server determines the output type of the `CASE` statement by the last return value. (In any case, itt has an algorithm for determining the return type when individual `THEN` statements are mixed.)

So, it sees your `CASE` statement as typed to whatever `FTBL_TEST_SCORES.TEST_SCORE_VALUE` is, which is probably inconsistent with the earlier `varchar` return values of the `CASE` statement.

Fix that, and the `HASHBYTES` function should work, as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
+convert(varchar(10),ISNULL(TEST_SCORE_VALUE,''))
```

Turns out that should've been:

```
+convert(varchar(10),ISNULL(TEST_SCORE_VALUE,0))
```

and then it all worked fine.